# What are the pros and cons of calling jQuery functionality via these 2 different methods?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to understand what the differences are (if any) between these 2 ways of calling JavaScript/jQuery functions.

Method 1, in `document.ready()`:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.popup', popup);
```

then

```
function popup() {
    $(this) // do something    
}
```

Method 2, in `document.ready()`:

```
popup();
```

then

```
function popup() {
    $("a.popup").click(function (e) {
        // do something here
    });
}
```

All advice appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean pros and cons of using `.on("click", ...)` and `.click(...)` specifically?

Comment: $('body') is slower then $('a.popup') and doesn't work on mobile devices as you expect

Comment: @Floremin - I was more questioning any event rather than just click. Things like does 1 preprocess everything on initiation and the other only do things when requested? Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

In method 2, the `popup` function is likely to be called only once, otherwise you attach the same function `onclick` several times, which propably is not what you want.
Therefore there is no great benefit in writing the `popup` function's body elsewhere than directly in `document.ready()`.

Advantage of method 1 is if you want to attach the same function to various events and/or various elements, e.g. `onclick`, `onmousemove` etc. This way you won't have to write the function's body twice.

In short, i don't see benefits in method 2, whereas i see some in method 1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, but I think you're asking what the difference between calling the jQuery [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method and the jQuery [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) method, right?

As in:

```
$someEl.on('click', someFunc);
// or
$someEl.click(someFunc);
```

Like this, both are pretty much equivalent. However with the .on() method you have the opportunity to introduce namespacing (explained in the first link) to your element's events. Like so:

```
$someEl.on('click.do1', someFunc1);
$someEl.on('click.do2', someFunc2);
```

So if in a later progress you want to remove or trigger only one of your callback functions (someFunc1, someFunc2), you'll be able to do so by calling:

```
$someEl.off('click.do1');
$someEl.trigger('click.do2');
```

Hope this helps